# How to JIT compile IR code from string

Tags: llvm, jit, llvm-ir

I've got such a problem. I've written my own IR code generator. It saves IR into a string. And now I want to JIT compile this IR code using LLVM. But all functions and API's I've found only gets llvm::Function as an arg. But how can I compile an IR code saved in the string?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `llvm::parseIR` function [defined here](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a8117bf6481e11cf7e95d56dc00991849).